# Fallback fonts with Jetpack Compose in Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've been rehearsing for a while but I still have no clue about how to do it. What I know so far is that Typeface has a CustomFallbackBuilder on which you define the font families which you want to fallback if one fails to load the text, but this is graphics Typeface, not compose.

So what I'm asking here if there's a way of specifying on my Android App a list of fallback custom fonts so in case that the first one fails to load any character or whatever, the next one applies.